# Android StudioでのJacksonでのJsonデータ表示について

Tags: java, android-studio, json, jackson

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            JackSon response = mapper.readValue(


             new URL("http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getAreas"),
                    JackSon.class);
            String m = response.get("response").get(0).get("area").asText();

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

            textView.setText(String.valueOf(m));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

上記のコードでは、`response.get`のgetに`Cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String)'`と言うエラーが出ています。

```
@Data
public class JackSon {
    private Area response;

    @Data
    public class Area {
        private String[] area;
    }
}
```

このコードをどうようにすれば表示されるようになりますか？

```
[
  {
    "a": "xxx",
    "b": yyy
  },
  {
    "a": "xxxx",
    "b": yyyy
  },
  {
    "a": "xx",
    "b": yy
  }
]
```

上記のURLではなくこのような形のJSONデータを表示する場合どのように変えればよいですか？

Comment: コードと期待値がバラバラでやりたいことがよくわからないのですが。表示したい要素は"area"ではなく"a"/"b"なのですか？

Comment: 追記：表示したいのはjson文字列そのものなのでしょうか？であればjsonをparseすること自体が必要ありませんのでJacksonを使用せずに、HttpResponseクラス等でhttp://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getAreasのレスポンスを表示すればよいだけです。

Answer (score 1):

JavaBeanクラス`JackSon`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.List;

public class JackSon {

    @JsonProperty("response")
    private Response response;

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }


    public static class Response {

        @JsonProperty("area")
        private List<String> area;

        public void setArea(List<String> area) {
            this.area = area;
        }

        public List<String> getArea() {
            return area;
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JackSon response = null;
        try {
            response = mapper.readValue( new URL("http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getAreas"), JackSon.class);

        final List<String> area = response.getResponse().getArea();
        final String s = area.toString();
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

            textView.setText(String.valueOf(m));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 上記のコードでは、`response.get`のgetに`Cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String)'`と言うエラーが出ています。

`@Data`は[Lombokのアノテーション](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)だと思いますので、自動でgetterが生成されています。従ってareaデータを取得するコードは

```
response.getResponse().getArea();
```

となります。
(なお、質問とは直接関係ないですが、`Area`クラスを非staticな内部クラスとして定義する必要は無いですし、一般的にはそのようにすべきではないです。)

---

> 上記のURLではなくこのような形のJSONデータを表示する場合どのように変えればよいですか？

トップレベルが`[]`なJSONの変換については、配列に変換するかリストに変換するかでやり方が変わります。

```
@Data
class MyData {
    private String a;
    private int b;
}
```

というように定義したクラスに対して:

a)配列に変換する場合

```
MyData[] myDataArray = mapper.readValue(..., MyData[].class);
```

b)リストに変換する場合

```
List<MyData> myDataList = mapper.readValue(..., new TypeReference<List<MyData>>(){});
```

(ただし、リストへ変換したい場合でも、`TypeReference`を使用せず、一旦前者の方法で配列に変換した後それをリストへ変換したほうが速いそうです。下記参考リンク参照。)

参考:

- [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349488/4506703)